# Waiting or not exiting the code block in getting json

Tags: objective-c, json, get

I am using GET method on Json. The GET method is inside a for loop, and the issue is it is not finishing the task or not getting the result. Instead the loop increments. I've placed a breakpoint inside the block where I am setting the result data to a NSDictionary but it never goes there.

Is it possible for the GET method to be directly called. I mean the code will be read line by line. And it will not skip or wait for the json to finish processing?

Here's what I've done:

```
- (void)downloadJsonFeed
{
for(int i = 1;i < self.numberOfEpisodes;i++)
{
    NSString *endPoint = [[[[baseJsonUrl stringByAppendingString:getEpisodes]stringByAppendingString:self.title]stringByAppendingString:@"&episodeNumber="]stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i]];
    NSLog(@"End point %@",endPoint);
    [JsonDownload getJson:token andEndpointString:endPoint WithHandler:^(__weak id result)
    {
        NSArray *episodeArray =result;
        //will do some task here
    }];

}

}


- (void)getJson:(NSString *)authData andEndpointString:(NSString  *)urlString WithHandler:(void(^)(__weak id result))handler
{
NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//NSString *auth = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer {%@}", authData];

[urlRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
[urlRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[urlRequest setValue:authData forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask =[defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
                                                   completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                       if(error == nil)
                                                       {
                                                           id returnedObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
                                                           handler(returnedObject);
                                                       }
                                                       else{
                                                           NSLog(@"error %@",error);
                                                       }
                                                   }];
[dataTask resume];
}
```

I've placed a break point in this line `NSArray *episodeArray =result;` and it never goes there. But when I put the break point on `[JsonDownload getJson:token andEndpointString:endPoint WithHandler:^(__weak id result)` line it is responding

And on the commented line `//will do some task here` I need to a task there before getting another json again. But I can't cause it never go inside the code block

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by replacing white space characters in my endPoint by %20